# Array manipulation with space char; iteration

Tags: c, arrays

I'm writing a program that receives an array and an integer x. To each word of the array (text[i]!=' '), the program should reduce the word to x integers and apply this to all the words. E.g.

If the user writes "Hello Im Kevin" and defines x=2, the program should return "he Im Ke".

This is what I have for now, but it only works for the first word...

The problem is that I don't know how to tell the program to run the algorithm again after a space and before the end of the string '\0'

```
char text[SIZE], new[SIZE];
int x, i, length;

void truncW ()
{
    printf("Insert text!\n");

    fgets (text, SIZE, stdin);

    printf("\nInsert number of chars per word.\n");

    scanf("%d",&x);

    while (text[i]!=' '){
        i++;
        memmove(new, text, x);
    }

    printf("%s", new);
}

int main()
{
    truncW();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @interjay , edited. Any suggestion about the iteration implementation?

Comment: code is much easier to rid if you indent it properly :) I would also recommend not making all your variables global.

Comment: There is a difference between `return` and `print`. As currently written, you function does not `return` anything.

Comment: @hugomg , exactly, that's the problem. I don't know how to apply this to all the stdin

Comment: @NatashaDutta , he returns, but only the first word. If I write "hello " and define x as 2, he returns he. The problem is that I don't know how to tell the program to run the algorithm again after a space and before the end of the string '\0'

Comment: @bauer with a `void` as function return type, how can __anyting__ be `return`ed?

Comment: 0) try not to use C++ keywords, like 'new' 1) check the returned value from fgets() to assure the operation was successful  2) check the returned value from scanf() to assure the operation was successful 3) this line: 'memmove(new, text, x);' is always copying  the same characters to the same place, you only want to do that once per word

Comment: regarding this line: 'int x, i, length;' It is almost always a bad idea to have more than one statement/variable declaration per line.   Amongst other problems the 'real world' would reject the code due to the multiple variable declarations on one line.  In the 'real world' quality control will require that each variable be commented,  often an automated utility will produce sections of the software detail design document  and will reject the multiple variables on one line .  Might as well get into good programming practices up front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void truncW(void){
    char text[SIZE], new[SIZE];
    int x, i, j, n;

    printf("Input text!\n");
    fgets(text, SIZE, stdin);

    printf("\nInput number of chars per word.\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    for(i=j=n=0; text[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(text[i]!=' '){
            if(n < x){//Copy restrictions
                new[j++] = text[i];
                ++n;
            }
        } else {
            new[j++] = text[i];
            n = 0;
        }
    }
    new[j] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", new);
}
```

Comment: what does 'n' variable is responsible for?

Comment: @bauer It counts the copy number of characters.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest,

1. Read the line using `fgets()`

   ```
    fgets (text, SIZE, stdin);
   ```
2. define a temporary `char` array to hold the modified o/p.

   ```
   char buf[SIZE] = {0};
   ```
3. Tokenize using `strtok()` using space (`" "`) as delimiter

   ```
   char * token = NULL;
   token = (text, " \n");
   ```
4. If the token is not `NULL`, print exactly `n` number (taken from user) of `char`s using `snprintf()` to the temporary array.

   ```
   snprintf(buf, n+1, "%s ", token);
   ```
5. Go to step 3 and continue until `strtok()` returns NULL.
6. Finally, print the temporary array.

   ```
   printf("%s", buf);
   ```

Comment: could you edit my code with that suggestions, please?

Comment: @bauer I have updated my answer with sample code snippet, you can try now and let me know. :-)

Comment: @Natasha Dutta Good answer. As for me I would not use strtok because it changes the original string. From the assignment it is not clear whether it is allowed to change it.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks. but it uses `text` which is modifiable, IMHO. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Natasha Dutta O'k.:)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN 50

void TruncateWords(char* Str, int WordLen)
{
    char Temp[MAXLEN];
    memset(Temp, 0, sizeof(Temp));

    char* pch = strtok(Str, " ");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        strncat(Temp, pch, WordLen);
        strcat(Temp, " ");
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    size_t Len = strlen(Temp) - 1;      // Don't copy the last added space
    strncpy(Str, Temp, Len);
    Str[Len] = '\0';        // strncpy doesn't null-terminate it in this case
}

int main()
{
    char Text[MAXLEN];
    int WordLen;

    printf("Insert text!\n");
    fgets(Text, sizeof(Text), stdin);
    Text[strlen(Text) - 1] = '\0';      // Get rid of fgets's \n

    printf("\nInsert number of chars per word.\n");
    scanf("%d", &WordLen);

    TruncateWords(Text, WordLen);

    puts(Text);

    return 0;
}
```

You should also add some checks for the value of `WordLen` - probably shouldn't be greater than `MAXLEN`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int rendsiz(char* str, char* delimiters, int x)
{
   char*h = NULL, *data = strdup(str);
   h = strtok(data, delimiters);
   int count = 0, lg = 0;
   while(h)
   {
     lg = strlen(h);
     if(lg>=x)count+=x+1;
     else count+=lg+1;
     h = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
   }
   free(data);
   return count;
}

void custprintf(char *data, char* delimiters, int x)
{
   char* st = strdup(data); //dup string, strtok mage change on the passed string
   int offset = 0, siz = 0, lg = 0, bufsiz = rendsiz(data, delimiters, x);
   char* t=NULL, *buf=(char *)malloc(bufsiz);
   memset(buf, 0, bufsiz);
   t = strtok(st, delimiters); #split string by " "
   while(t)
   {
     lg = strlen(t);
     if(lg>=x)siz = x;
     else siz = lg;
     memcpy(buf+offset, t, siz);
     buf[offset+siz]=' ';
     offset+=siz+1;
     t = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
   }
   printf("%s\n", buf);
   free(buf);
   free(st);
}
```

this actually work

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that modifies the string in-place with no need for a temporary array:

```
void truncate( char *str, size_t len )
{
  size_t r; // index from which we read the next character (source)
  size_t w; // index to which we write the next character (target)
  size_t l; // Temp counter

  r = w = 0;
  l = len;

  while ( str[r] )
  {
    if ( str[r] == ' ' )    // If we see a blank, reset the counter
    {                       // and write the blank to the target index
      l = len;
      str[w++] = str[r++];
    }
    else if ( l )           // If we don't see a blank and our counter
    {                       // isn't 0, write the character to the
      --l;                  // target index, advance both source and
      str[w++] = str[r++];  // target indices, decrement the counter
    }
    else                    // If we don't see a blank and the counter
    {                       // is 0, advance the source index.
      r++;
    }
  }
  str[w] = 0;             // Make sure the result is 0-terminated
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Should this be marked "homework":-)?

I would avoid using `memmove`. That can only lead to trouble. Since you are already willing to allocate a fixed buffer you can simply iterate over the array, filling the new array on the fly:

```
/* x is max characters per word (as per your example);
   y counts those characters */
int y = 0;

while (*text) {
    int is_space = *text == ' ';
    int must_show = y <= x;

    if (must_show) {
        *new++ = *text++;
        y++;
    } else {
        while (*text != ' ') text++;
    }
    if (is_space || !must_show) y = 0;
}
*new = '\0';
```

I have not tested this though. And the style may not conform to your requirements.